# Managing service accounts in an RPM spec

Tags: user-accounts, services, rpm

I've been given a partially-complete RPM spec for a service we're writing.  It gets as far as making the required directories, copying files, setting permissions, etc., but it doesn't make the required system account that the service will run under.  I was told that it's best for the RPM to take care of this, so I've added

```
Requires(pre): /usr/sbin/useradd

%pre
useradd -r -d /path/to/program -s /bin/false myservice
```

This succeeds in making the user account (and associated group), so later on when it tries to set ownership / permissions on the service's files, that succeeds as well.

My current problem is, a) if the user account already exists, the RPM install fails because `useradd` fails (because the user already exists); and b) I don't know how to have `rpm -e myservice` also remove the associated user and group.

Comment: // , Would you consider using FPM?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I actually solved this independently, by looking at other RPM specs that did similar things.  If you just want to add a user (conditionally), use Ignacio's link.  I did this:

```
Requires(pre): /usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/bin/getent
Requires(postun): /usr/sbin/userdel

%pre
/usr/bin/getent group myservice || /usr/sbin/groupadd -r myservice
/usr/bin/getent passwd myservice || /usr/sbin/useradd -r -d /path/to/program -s /sbin/nologin myservice

%postun
/usr/sbin/userdel myservice
```

This makes sure that the RPM "cleans up after itself" but still provides the ability to install even if the account already exists.

Comment: Although this answers the question, it is worth reading the note in the Fedora link [link](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:UsersAndGroups) posted by Ignacio about why removing the user/group is not desirable.

Comment: There is an UID and GID reuse issue (when the deleted user has the highest UID/GID), that makes any automated use of userdel a bad idea.

Comment: On my CentOS 6.7 I removed the /usr/sbin/groupadd command since the useradd command will create the group itself. Also the useradd will exit with an error when a group of the same name already exists.

Comment: rpmlint report "W: dangerous-command-in-%postun userdel" if you use it

Answer (score 6):

Either of the two previous answers are production ready as those methods will delete the user if the package is upgrade.  Yum installs the new package then removes the old package. This will leave you without an user. Not cool!

Use this method instead:

```
%postun
case "$1" in
   0) # This is a yum remove.
      /usr/sbin/userdel myservice
   ;;
   1) # This is a yum upgrade.
      # do nothing
   ;;
 esac
```

Comment: Major oversight. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The response from Coderer is good but the second pre command give me an error on Centos 7. The group must be specified.

```
Requires(pre): /usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/bin/getent
Requires(postun): /usr/sbin/userdel

%pre
/usr/bin/getent group myservice > /dev/null || /usr/sbin/groupadd -r myservice
/usr/bin/getent passwd myservice > /dev/null || /usr/sbin/useradd -r -d /path/to/program -s /sbin/nologin -g myservice myservice

%postun
/usr/sbin/userdel myservice
```

I added also redirect to /dev/null to ignore unwanted echos.